# Camunda authentication and identity service with Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, business-process-management, bpmn, camunda

We're using the Camunda RestAPI to communicate with the camunda-engine in the backend, so far so good, but we haven't been able to enable the Camunda authentication service so that users/rolls can only instanciate/claim/complete/see (when requesting via http) the tasks and processes which are assigned to them or their groups.

We're also using the spring boot implementation of the configuration, we have tried several things, but non has work so far as anyone can do anything and it's not even asking for credentials, so I was thinking I may be doing something wrong considering how complicated it has been.

So the question is, what are the standard steps we need to take to make these services work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Camunda is running bundled with a Tomcat server which allows LDAP, so one way might be to let your Tomcat do the permission management. In other words, you might limit the user access via the hosting web server.